# Getting DatePicker to place the selected date in the closest input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker that works when I click on the input field; however, I also wanted for it to work when I click on a font-awesome icon that is joined to the input field.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input name="DelDate" type="datetime" id="datepicker" class="form-control" style="width:80%!important;" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar dp" style="cursor: pointer;font-size:x-large"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $('.dp, #datepicker').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        constrainInput: true
    });
```

From this code, if I click on the inside of the input field, and then select a specific date, that date will then be dropped into the input field.  Great!

But, if I click on the calendar icon, right next to the input field, the datepicker calendar pops-up, and does not drop the selected date into the input filed.
How do I bind the fa-calendar click to the input field so both methods yield a date getting dropped into the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign click to your icon then focus on date picker.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dp, #datepicker').datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    constrainInput: true
  });

  $('.dp').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="input-group date">
  <input name="DelDate" type="datetime" id="datepicker" class="form-control" style="width:80%!important;" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar dp" style="cursor: pointer;font-size:x-large"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```